# How to set manual timezone offset for specific region

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, timezone

As you know Node.js gets its timezone data from the [ICU](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/doc/contributing/maintaining-icu.md#time-zone-data) library, aka International Components for Unicode. recently our region (Asia/Tehran) timezone daylight rules has been changed.

```
console.log(new Date().toString())
Sat Mar 25 2023 17:05:18 GMT+0430
```

the correct output should be like this:

```
Sat Mar 25 2023 16:05:18 GMT+0330
```

I dont want to use external Date library like moment. is there any solution to override timezone offset for whole node environment? or is there any way to force nodejs to use OS timezone?

Comment: The change is noted in the [IANA news](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tzdb/NEWS) has it not propogated to ICU yet?

Comment: `new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: 'Asia/Tehran'});` gives +3.30 time in jsfiddle. not sure about node

Comment: Same here, showing correct offset Node v18.12.1. `env TZ='Asia/Tehran' node -e 'console.log(new Date().toString());'` -> `Sat Mar 25 2023 16:28:45 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)`

Comment: Thank you pilchard. my Node was not update.

Comment: DST is now being split along religious lines, so even current "timezones" may need to be revised to include whether DST is in use or not in the same geographic location, e.g. [Lebanon](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/mar/26/lebanon-split-into-two-time-zones-in-row-over-daylight-saving).